# Running php files stored on OneDrive

Tags: php, apache, xampp, onedrive

I am developing a php project, having the project files stored on OneDrive so that I can access them from anywhere.

I have set up XAMPP, with a `VirtualHost` pointing to my project folder inside OneDrive so that I can run it in my browser.

This has been working great up until yesterday, when OneDrive started crashing and I had to reinstall it. Now I'm no longer able to run php files stored on OneDrive.

I get this error in my browser:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'D:/OneDrive/MyProject/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
```

My OneDrive folder is `D:\OneDrive`. If I set up a `VirtualHost` pointing to `D:\`, I am able to run files such as `D:\index.php` or `D:\MyProject\index.php` in my browser. But I'm not able to run files such as `D:\OneDrive\index.php` or `D:\OneDrive\MyProject\index.php`.

Does anyone have an idea what might cause this issue?

**Edit:**

The issue does not seem to be related to `.htaccess`, as the behavior is independent of whether a `.htaccess` file exists in the project folder or not.

Here is my `VirtualHost`, in case anyone is interested:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myproject.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/OneDrive/MyProject/"
    ServerName myproject.com
    ServerAlias www.myproject.com 

    <Directory "D:/OneDrive/MyProject/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: show your virtualhost path. as well as .htaccess setup.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu See my updated question.

Comment: I had the same issue. Your antivirus might be the problem. I am using Bitdefender and went to Application Access (under the Safe Files settings), and gave permissions to Apache and PHP CLI. Now it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not been able to solve the issue, but I've found a workaround:

1. Store the project files outside of OneDrive.
2. Make a [symbolic link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) in the OneDrive folder to the project folder outside of OneDrive.

With this setup I'm able to run my PHP application, since the project files are not physically located in the OneDrive folder, and the project files are still uploaded and backed up on OneDrive due to the symbolic link.

Comment: Perfect !  `mklink /J D:\myCompany\php\tests C:\Users\myUser\OneDrive\prog\php\tests`

Answer (score 3):

This bug is not fixed still. After Windows 10 May 2019 Update, the bug reappeared and it's not fixed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to right-click OneDrive's icon in the Notification area, choose Settings > Settings > and uncheck Files on Demand.

Optionally, you can leave that, but just right click the folder in OneDrive that's giving you grief and choose the option to always keep a local copy of the folder.

Comment: That's a good idea. I already had all the files stored locally, with Files on Demand turned off, so this was not the issue in my case.

Comment: Do not exists in 2023 version :/

Answer (score -1):

I think is fixed now (2018-11-26) - Now, sites are working again in OneDrive. I'm sure it was a OneDrive app problem that was fixed recently.