# Insufficient permissions when installing laravel in Onedrive folder

Tags: laravel, permissions, installation, xampp, onedrive

I am currently trying to do a new Laravel install in a Onedrive folder with the following command:

`laravel new blog` or `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Unfortunately, I get the following error: 
`PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(C:\Users\jordy\OneDrive\Websites\www.blog.nl/laravel_7198089e82dcd0b2debf8486652dfae3.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Users\jordy\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\laravel\installer\src\NewCommand.php on line 133`, including a few similar ones.

I run my command prompt as an Administrator on Windows 10, and my user account has full permissions on the Onedrive folder. If I try to do it in another directory outside the Onedrive, it works correctly.

How is this possible? Does Onedrive blocks something?

Comment: this most likely will not work as you do not have root server access to onedrive server, even with full local admin rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that Bitdefender AntiVirus was the problem. I went to Application Access (under the Safe Files settings), and gave permissions to Apache and PHP CLI. Now it works.

([Running php files stored on OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528273/running-php-files-stored-on-onedrive))

Actually, this also fixes the blank page issue on Laravel installations.